# Graphql request in .net web api returns not expected data

Tags: .net, graphql

I try to use `graphql` with `.net5 web api` following [red gate example](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/building-and-consuming-graphql-api-in-asp-net-core-3-1/). I managed to make query working, but it always returns same data, and it returns something wrong.

Here is a screenshot from rider on the return point of graphQl controller:[image]

In debug I can see that my database service returns simple list of TodoItems.

To test graphql I use GraphiQL and see serialized json of what is on screenshot 1. I expect to see only requested items[image]

Looks like grapqh query returns wrong json to me. Fully serialized todoitems are buried inside this object.

All code is basically copy-paste from red-gate example, I just use TodoItems instead.
Controller code:

```
[Route("graphql")]
public class GraphQlController : Controller
{
    // GET
    private readonly ISchema _schema;
    private readonly IDocumentExecuter _executer;
    public GraphQlController(ISchema schema, 
        IDocumentExecuter executer)
    {
        _schema = schema;
        _executer = executer;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] 
        GraphQLQueryDTO query)
    {
        var result = await _executer.ExecuteAsync(_ =>
        {
            _.Schema = _schema;
            _.Query = query.Query;
            _.Inputs = query.Variables?.ToInputs();
            
        });

        if(result.Errors?.Count > 0)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return Ok(result.Data);
    }
}
```

Query :

```
public TodoItemQuery(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<TodoItemType>>("items", "", null,
            c => 
                context.TodoItems.ToList());
        
        Field<TodoItemType>("item","", new QueryArguments(
            new QueryArgument<IntGraphType>{Name = "id"}), c =>
        {
            var id = c.GetArgument<int>("id");
            return context.TodoItems.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
        });
    }
```

TodoItemType:

```
public class TodoItemType : ObjectGraphType<TodoItem>
{
    public TodoItemType()
    {
        Name = nameof(TodoItem);
        Field(_ => _.Id).Description("Item's Id");
        Field(_ => _.Done).Description("If this item is done");
        Field(_ => _.Note).Description("Description");
        Field(_ => _.Priority).Description("How important it is");
        Field(_ => _.Title).Description("Title");
        Field(_ => _.ListId).Description("List id");
        Field(_ => _.Created).Description("Created datetime");
        Field(_ => _.CreatedBy).Description("Author");
        Field(_ => _.LastModifiedBy).Description("Modifier");
    }
}
```

TodoItem:

```
 public class TodoItem : AuditableEntity, IHasDomainEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ListId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }
  
    public PriorityLevel Priority { get; set; }


    private bool _done;
   
    public bool Done
    {
        get => _done;
        set
        {
            if (value == true && _done == false)
            {
                DomainEvents.Add(new TodoItemCompletedEvent(this));
            }

            _done = value;
        }
    }
   
    public List<DomainEvent> DomainEvents { get; set; } = new List<DomainEvent>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it; basically one should not follow red-gate example which pops out 1st in google. Use [this one](https://thecloudblog.net/post/build-a-basic-graphql-server-with-asp.net-core-and-entity-framework-in-10-minutes/). Red-gate is heavily outdated.
Most errors were in services configurations, I had to add several nuget packages which I was not even aware about.